# Post Deployment Configuration of MDB using JCA Inbound Socket Resource

Tags: sockets, glassfish, ejb, jca, inbound

I have a message driven bean that is being invoked from data received on a TCP socket via a JCA Resource Adapter in a GlassFish 3.1.1 application server.  The deployment descriptor in the sun-ejb-jar.xml file, specifies the URL and port of the socket.  When the MDB is deployed, I see the app server execute the endpointActivation() method in the resource adapter with the MessageEndpointFactory and ActivationSpec as parameters.

This works fine when the URL and port are known before deployment and can be specified in the XML file, but now I need the ability to change the TCP socket during runtime in my EJB code.  I couldn't find any references in the JCA spec about how to do this during runtime.

For reference, I downloaded the specification from Oracle's website.
[J2EE Connector Architecture Specification Version 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#J2EE_CONNECTOR-1.5-FR-SPEC-G-F)

Basically, I'd like to move the following XML code that populates the ActivationSpec into my EJB code.

```
<sun-ejb-jar>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <ejb>
      <ejb-name>MyInboundSocketMDB</ejb-name>
      <mdb-resource-adapter>
        <resource-adapter-mid>jca-sockets-rar</resource-adapter-mid>
        <activation-config>
          <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>url</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>localhost</activation-config-property-value>
          </activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property-name>port</activation-config-property-name>
            <activation-config-property-value>5006</activation-config-property-value>
          </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
      </mdb-resource-adapter>
    </ejb>
  </enterprise-beans>
</sun-ejb-jar>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your activation-config-property-value in the glassfish web admin.